# MySQL: Select prior 5 and following 5 entries by date, 1 query, without subqueries

Tags: mysql, select

I try to get "n" entries with date lower and "n" entries with date "higher" than one selected date.

*Example DB:* (ordered by employment_date)

```
id  | employment_date | name
-------------------------------
23  | 1980-01-11      | peter
21  | 1980-09-02      | sandra
34  | 1982-04-12      | steven
4   | 1982-06-14      | claudia
45  | 1983-10-12      | chuck
56  | 1984-03-16      | bob
1   | 1987-03-23      | kevin
```

So what i want is to display claudia and then show the "n" people who got employed before her and the "n" people who got employed after her. With "n" being 2, for claudia i'd want: *sandra,steven,**claudia**,chuck,bob*.

Of course i could just do two queries but since i have to dock into a given structure of dataproviders i kind of have to do it in **one simple query** that can only use **Select, Join/Left Join /Inner Join, From, Where, Group By, Order By and Limit**.
Preferably without subqueries.

The id's aren't contiguous by the way.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Wouldn't that be `Sandra` instead of `Peter` in your example?

Comment: Oh i always mix sandra and peter. they look so much alike ;D

Answer (score 2):

What about the ugly (a.o.t. good or bad)

```
(
SELECT id,@basedate:=employment_date AS employment_date,name
FROM employees WHERE name='claudia'
)
UNION
(
SELECT * FROM employees
ORDER BY if (employment_date>@basedate,employment_date,'9999-12-31') ASC
LIMIT 2
)
UNION
(
SELECT * FROM employees
ORDER BY if (employment_date<@basedate,employment_date,'0001-01-01') DESC
LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY employment_date ASC
```

Line-of-thought breakdown:

- First select the base row, remembering the date
- Then (using the remembered basedate) select the later dates, killing the earlier ones by setting them to the end of MySQL date space
- Then do the same thing with the earlier dates
- Lastly sort as needed

Comment: I have to vote the answer up because it is really, really good but as i mentioned, i have to use this given structure and that makes the UNION solution almost impossible. But thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your OQ to elaborate what is and what is not easy/possible to use?